# JUnit test: caused an ERROR: javax/ejb/Local

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, junit, mockito

After having mocked all the dependencies necessary for testing a method, I eventually get this error message when testing. ERROR: javax/ejb/Local - NoClassDefFoundError.

Any clue on how can I solve this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is your `j2ee.jar` on the classpath?

Comment: @Reimeus all the dependencies are handled by mvn

Comment: What scope does `j2ee.jar` have? If it's in `provided` scope, as provided by the application server, it won't be in `test` scope too.